# OpenProject Email Notification no pictures inside the mail

Tags: email, notifications, openproject

i installed and configured open project on my ubuntu 18.04 server. I have one little problem, maybe someone can help me:

I configured a SMTP Server in the email notification settings. Testmail and sending email notification is working. But images are not visible inside the email. I only see a boarder with a question mark as you can see in the picture.

[image]

When I open the email in the editor and decode the base64 string I can see that the image url show to "/openproject/api/v3/attachments/10/content". I think the hostname is missing, but the hostname is configured correctly in the settings.

Whats the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is (still) a bug but work has been started today.

In case you want to follow up on this issue, here is the bug report: https://community.openproject.com/projects/openproject/work_packages/29523/activity